# Edit HTML opening and closing tag at the same time in RubyMine

Tags: tags, rubymine

Is there any way to edit related tags at the same time using a shortcut?

For example, changing `<h3>Task anlegen</h3>` to `<h2>Task anlegen</h2>` by selecting only the opening or closing tags?

Command+W selects the current word but I'd like to select both at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Refactor` | **Rename** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>), then edit one of the tags and another one will be edited to the same value automatically.